# JSQMessagesViewController set recipient firebase id

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have implemented firebase firechat by following raywenderlick at https://www.raywenderlich.com/122148/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat

but the issue is it is using Anonymous mode.

My app have obtained 2 firebase uid and when User1 logging and send message, I need to set User2 firebase uid so that both can talk. However, my class implement JSQMessagesViewController swift class and only able to set senderId and senderDisplayName and I don't find variable like recipientId.

The method didPressSendButton too doesn't have anywhere to set the recipient firebaseid.

```
 override func didPressSendButton(button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: NSDate!) {

    let itemRef = messageRef.childByAutoId()

    let messageItem = [
        "text": text,
        "senderId": senderId
    ]

    itemRef.setValue(messageItem)

    JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageSentSound()

    finishSendingMessage()

    isTyping = false

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can created your own message object and as long as it conforms to the `JSQMessageData` protocol it will work with the controller. Then add your custom variable to that object. There is an example here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38884743/5894123