# Argument labels do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am working on a messaging app using JSQMessagesViewController, and I want to associate another variable, an Integer `score`, with each message (along with the defaults such as `senderID`, `text`, and `displayName`). This is how I attempt to implement this:

```
func addMessage(id: String, text: String, displayName: String, score: Int) {

    // Make sure the character count is between 10 and 140, then add message to message list to display
    if (text.characters.count <= 10 || text.characters.count >= 140) {

    }
    else {
        let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, displayName: displayName, text: text, score: score)
        messages.append(message)
    }

}
```

However I am getting the following error message:

`Argument labels '(senderId:, displayName:, text:, score:)' do not match any available overloads`

I can only assume that this is because there is some pre-set definition as to what data the JSQMessage object can hold, I am just unsure how to override it so that I can associate an additional variable with my messages.

Note: I tried to directly change the code in the JSQMessagesViewController framework itself (within the `JSQMessage.h` and `JSQMessage.m` files) to add an extra variable but this just causes more errors and I am afraid I will mess something up.

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I think I figured out how to do it!

```
import UIKit
import JSQMessagesViewController

class CustomMessage: JSQMessage {
    var score : Int

    init(senderId:String, displayName:String, text:String, score:Int) {
        self.score = score
        super.init(senderId:senderId, displayName:displayName, text:text)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

However I am now getting an error after `super.init` as such: `must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'JSQMessage'`

Comment: hii i also want to add another paramter for message id @Ahad Sheriff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just subclass the JSQMessage object and add your extra variable to your subclassed object.
Then it will conform and have all the same methods.

Edit:

It looks like I might have miss lead you, the documentation instructs you to conform to the `JSQMessageData` protocol. I did it like this

```
class Message: NSObject, JSQMessageData {
var text_: String?
var senderId_: String?
var date_: NSDate?
var senderDisplayName_: String?
var isMediaMessage: Bool?
var score: Int?               ***** Here is your new Variable

init(text: String?, senderId: String?, senderDisplayName: String?, score: Int?, date: NSDate) {
    self.text_ = text
    self.senderId_ = senderId
    self.isOutBound_ = isOutBound
    self.date_ = date
    self.senderDisplayName_ = senderDisplayName
    self.score_ = score       *****
}

func text() -> String? {
    return text_
}
func score() -> Int? {        *****
    return score_
}

func senderId() -> String? {
    return senderId_
}

func date() -> NSDate? {
    return date_
}

func senderDisplayName() -> String? {
    return senderDisplayName_
}

func isMediaMessage() -> Bool {
    return isMediaMessage_
}

func messageHash() -> UInt {
    return UInt(self.hash)
}
```

}

You can still do it the other way but Protocols are the way to go.

Let me know if that helped I may have just confused you more :) But I will try and clarify. Good Luck

Comment: Could you check out the edit I made to my question? I think I almost got it, I am just getting a tiny error. Thanks for the awesome help by the way you're great!

Comment: Hey just checking if you saw my edit and if that helped.

Comment: i want to add messageID property to JSQMessage from which class i would change and add a messageID property in objective c class instaled after pod

Comment: @DanielLeonard pls reply