# Swift 2.2, Firebase, JSQMessagesViewController - Cannot convert return expression of type [JSQMessage] to type JSQMessageData

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am trying to make a chat app. I have the login and part of the chat interface done, but when I try to configure the chat with the function `collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, 
    messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData` , it gives me the error 'Cannot convert return expression of type [JSQMessage] to type JSQMessageData!'

Here is my code for the MessagesViewController :

```
import UIKit
import JSQMessagesViewController
import Firebase



class MessagesViewController: JSQMessagesViewController {




override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!,
                             messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
    return message[indexPath.item].userMessages
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                             numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return message.count
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Here is the code for my custom class Messages:

```
import Foundation
import JSQMessagesViewController
import Firebase

class Messages {

dynamic var user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

dynamic var addedUsers = [String]()

dynamic var userMessages = [JSQMessage]()

dynamic var messageDates = [NSDate]()

}
```

The array messages is `var message = [Messages]()`

What is my error, Thank You in advance.

Comment: I think it should be it should be return message[indexPath.item]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I solved it myself. I experimented and found that I had to put 'messages[indexPath.item].userMessages[index Path.item]'. I realized that I needed to give the function every single message instead of the array. Thanks to all that helped!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to pass `JSQMessages` which you can do if you use `JSQMessages` instead of your custom class `Messages` but if you have more variables that you want to keep track of on your message object then you may need your custom implementation.

All You need to have your `Messages` class conform to the `JSQMessageData` Protocol. `JSQMessages` already conform to this which is why they work. I have outlined how I do this previously in another stackoverflow question which you can refer to as a guide if you get stuck. [Argument labels do not match any available overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864942/argument-labels-do-not-match-any-available-overloads/38884743?noredirect=1#comment65226902_38884743)

Best of luck let me know if there is more I can help you with.